# Im trying to set up a graph but keep gettin error "isolated expression"

Tags: metapost

```
beginfig(1);
numeric u;
path xaxis,yaxis;
Scale: 1=u
u=0.5in;
yaxis= (0,-4.1u)--(0,4.2u);
xaxis= (-4.1u,0)--(4.2u,0);
pickup pencircle scaled 1pt;
drawarrow xaxis;
drawarrow yaxis;
pickup pencircle scaled 0.1pt;
for i=0 upto 100: draw (-4+i*0.1,-4)*u--(-4+i*0.1,4)*u; endfor;
for i=0 upto 100: draw (-4,-4+i*0.1)*u--(4,-4+i*0.1)*u; endfor;
pickup pencircle scaled 0.25pt;
for i=0 upto 10: draw (-4+i,-4)*u--(-4+i,4)*u; endfor;
for i=0 upto 10: draw (-4,-4+i)*u--(4,-4+i)*u; endfor;
label.rt(btex $x$ etex, (4.2u,0));
label.top(btex $y$ etex, (0,4.2u));
endfig(1);
end.
```

Comment: Use the code markdown and formatting so this doesn't look like hieroglyphics.

Comment: how? I cant find where to do it at

Comment: @BritneyWiggins you can select the code and use the `{}` button on the top of the editing window.

Comment: Replace `Scale: 1=u` with `%Scale: 1=u`
and `endfig(1);` with `endfig;`.

Comment: @g.kov An answer, please (let me know when you've added it)

Comment: @egreg: Somehow I've missed your comment, the answer is added now.

Answer (score 6):

The code of the OP image has syntactic errors.
Luckily, the `metapost` program gives a user-friendly tips to find them.
The `metapost` program is upset with two lines in the code:
first complain

```
>> Scale
! Isolated expression.
<to be read again> 
                   :
l.4 Scale:
           1=u
?
```

points out to the line 4 (which is indicated as l.4) 
and says that `1=u` is an isolated expression,
i.e. it is meaningless in the context.
Since we can not guess what that line of code supposed to mean,
the simplest fix then would be to remove the line altogether
or (as a minimal correction) just make it a comment by prefixing it with `%`.

After this fix the `metapost` program's next complain is about line 19:

```
! Extra tokens will be flushed.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.19 endfig(
            1);
?
```

meaning that `(` token is not supposed to be there, the fix is to remove `(1)`.

After the two corrections the code looks like

```
beginfig(1);
numeric u;
path xaxis,yaxis;
%Scale: 1=u
u=0.5in;
yaxis= (0,-4.1u)--(0,4.2u);
xaxis= (-4.1u,0)--(4.2u,0);
pickup pencircle scaled 1pt;
drawarrow xaxis;
drawarrow yaxis;
pickup pencircle scaled 0.1pt;
for i=0 upto 100: draw (-4+i*0.1,-4)*u--(-4+i*0.1,4)*u; endfor;
for i=0 upto 100: draw (-4,-4+i*0.1)*u--(4,-4+i*0.1)*u; endfor;
pickup pencircle scaled 0.25pt;
for i=0 upto 10: draw (-4+i,-4)*u--(-4+i,4)*u; endfor;
for i=0 upto 10: draw (-4,-4+i)*u--(4,-4+i)*u; endfor;
label.rt(btex $x$ etex, (4.2u,0));
label.top(btex $y$ etex, (0,4.2u));
endfig;
end.
```

and the `metapost` program is happy to compile it.